# options binding with json object but matching by a json property

Tags: knockout.js

I've got an `observableArray` (`var array`) with json data like this:

```
{id:0, text:'blah'} ...
```

My value variable (`var val`) is exactly the same: `{id, text}`. 
My binding is

```
<select data-bind="options: array, optionsText: 'text', value: val">
```

But, I'm taking array data from ajax method and I'm initializing `val` as `val = ko.observable({id:1, text:'blahblah'})` and knockout can't match both objects (of course, there are not the same object).

So, I need a matching function by testing id values, *but* if I use the `optionsValue` binding, my value will not `{id, text}` anymore, but only `id`.

How can I preserve my binding as `{id,text}` but matching only by `id`?

Comment: Yeah it is better if you use proper code examples, rather than polluting your descriptions with it.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I was tilted and my zen-code was not the best.
Thanks for your work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing objects with arrays (and vice versa)

In Javascript arrays are simply a collection of items with a numeric key starting with zero. Arrays are surrounded by square brackets e.g.

```
var val = ['item 1'.'item 2','item 3'];
```

you get the item by its index number, which start with zero, e.g.

```
val[1] // Returns 'item 2'
```

If you remove an item, the array renumbers itself from the removed (slice) item(s).

Objects have keys (id, text)

```
var val = {id : 0, text : 'Text'};
```

You obtain the value of the associated key with either square brackets or a dot e.g.

```
`val.id` 
`val[id]`
```

If you store the data in an array, you can use the index as the id, e.g. if id = 0, `val[0]` will return 'item 1'

Once you have decided on the structure, you can decide how you want to retrieve items.

Note an array can hold more complex objects than strings, so an array can hold your object {id : 0, text 'words'} but then you have to iterate through the array using for or forEach etc to find the item.  If you can provide more details of the real data I can elaborate on which type of ko.observable , ko.observableArray etc to use

Comment: Thank you @brianlmerritt, I'll retry to explain it again: I've an json objects {id, text} array but I need that ko uses only id to check equality in an options/value binding, provinding value is also an {id, text} object...
Thanks a lot for your response.